# what does this syntax in styled-components actually mean?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I've just started using styled-components and saw that they call what i presume is a function like so:

```
import styled from "styled-components"

const Button = sytled.button` <--- this 
    // css goes here
`
```

I've never seem that syntax before and wanted to know if someone could point me to some docs about what it actually is.

Comment: The actual name of this feature is tagged template literals. In case anyone wants to search more documentation.  Here are a couple of small explanation articles https://wesbos.com/tagged-template-literals/      
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called tagged template literals. The "tag" is the function before the template literal, which is called with its parameters being the template and template's variables. The parameters are as follow:

1. An array with all the string parts **between** the `${variables}`.
2. First `${variable}` of the template.
3. Second `${variable}` of the template.
4. etc...

For example, I have written a function named `tag` that does the same as the function template literals use to process when you don't specify any tag function (a.k.a its default function):

```js
function tag(stringParts, ...values){
  return stringParts.reduce((accum, part, index) => accum + values[index-1] + part);
}
```

Calling it this way

```
tag`Hello, ${name}! I found ${count} results.`
```

yields the same result as

```
`Hello, ${name}! I found ${count} results.`
```

and the params fed to the tag function are `['Hello, ', '! I found ', ' results.']`, `name` and `count`.

Answer (score 0):

That's how you set the CSS rules for the `<button>` element.

So then you can use it as such:

```
<Button>Hello world</Button>
```

and all the styles you wrote above would get applied to all `<Button>` elements

Comment: I get that, its just I've never seen the syntax before. I'm assuming that it works the same as `styled.button(css)` but instead of invoking the function that way it uses `\`css\`` to do so, which is why i asked how it works.

Comment: @StrahinjaAjvaz the back tick syntax is explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: @StrahinjaAjvaz It would really help if you accepted my answer!

Comment: @SunilD. Can you add the resource to the answer? I think most of us were looking for the syntax explanation

Answer (score 0):

Styled-components is a library used for styling react components.

```
import styled from "styled-components"

const Button = sytled.button` <--- this 
  // css goes here
 `;

 `` <-- these are template literals which was introduced in ES6.
```

styled is an object here and when you say styled.button it means that we are styling html tags. So you can style a div, container, h1 etc. You want to use standard css to style these html tags and styled-components create a random classname for the same.

let's say you want to style a div. You name it a Wrapper. The naming covention is first letter always capital.

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
   background: #c0c0aa;  /* fallback for old browsers */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #1cefff, #c0c0aa);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
   background: linear-gradient(to right, #1cefff, #c0c0aa); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
 `;
```

now you can wrap your content in render () of react.

```
 <Wrapper>
  //Your code in render of react class goes here
  //thus instead of <div className = 'Wrapper'>
  //you use the above code
  //styled-components automatically generates random classnames solving major problems

 </ Wrapper>
```

for more information see Max Stoiber's keynote at React Amsterdam.
https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#motivation